# how do you open another website from my website

Tags: web

hi can anyone help me please

what i am trying to do is get another website  to open in a new window / tab

so someone would go to my site and not only would my website open but also the other website in a new / tab window without having to click any link or any thing it would just automatically open the other site in new tab/ window

Comment: i have seen people do this kinda like a pop up  that opens another website

Comment: What you have seen is true and it can be done!!!

Comment: I had missed an inverted comma in `onload="opennewsite()"`...Try using the updated script.Also ensure that everything I have mentioned in comments are followed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
         window.open('www.thedomain you want.com','_blank');
</script>
```

although based on the browser and it's settings it might work ok or not...

Comment: but i have seen people do this kinda like a pop up  that opens another website

Answer (score 0):

This is for opening another website in a new window/tab once your website has loaded completely.You don't need to click anything.Once your website is completely loaded,other website will automatically open.I have use  `www.thesiteIwant.com` as the URL for the other site you want to open.

```
window.open("http://www.thesiteIwant.com");
```

The above code by default opens a new window but if the user has selected to open new URLs in new tab then it will open the above site in new tab.

Complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function opennewsite() 
    //can be placed inside the head tag
    {
    window.open("http://thesiteIwant.com");
    }
</script>
<title> mysite </title>

</head>

<body onload="opennewsite()">
/*adding onload event handler will execute the function once your site body (content) has been completely loaded*/
//all the content here.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i have seen people do this kinda like a pop up  that opens another website

Comment: The code I have given you opens a new website but whether it opens in a new tab or window depends on the settings the user has saved.Opening a site in a tab/window is user preference

Comment: thanks mat ; ur amazing -) is it possible to do it using iframe or ??    as i am trying to do this using my wix site and i tried the script you gave me and didn't do anything

Comment: The above code should work irrespective of which host you are using(wix).Since javascript is a client side scripting language,it is executed by the browser.So this will work for sure.Check in your browser settings if you have blocked popups!!

Comment: Also check if javascript is enabled on your browser!!

Comment: What I gave you in the answer is the complete structure of a website with the script to open the other website automatically!!!You don't need the entire part!! You just have to copy the `<script> function opennewsite().....</script>` and place in the head of the index.html file you will find in your website root directory.Use search button in wix file tab to find this file.Also add `onload=opennewsite()` in the body tag(inline) of index.html.